# PageInit Jquery mobile not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, ios-simulator

Hi I'm new on phonegap jquerymobile ios, so I'm just trying to execute a simple alert message in the pageinit, but the event never fired.

Here is my jquery code.

```
          $('#myPage').live('pageInit', function(event){
                            navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is Working");
                            });
```

and here is the html code

```
  <div data-role="page" id="myPage">
      <div data-role="header">
          <h1>My Title</h1>
      </div><!-- /header -->
      <div data-role="content"> 
          <p>Hello world</p>        
          <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
              <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div><!-- /content -->

  </div><!-- /page -->
```

could anybody tell me what am I doing wrong or maybe It's problem of the simulator?

Answer (score 3):

The alert message is not firing because the you have used `pageInit` instead of `pageinit` in your jquery code.

Replace

```
$('#myPage').live('pageInit', function(event){
                            navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is Working");
                            });
```

with

```
$('#myPage').live('pageinit', function(event){
                            alert("PhoneGap is Working");
                            });
```

Your code will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I replace it like you say but not fired.

Comment: Have you added all required js and css files in your html file? Note that i have used only alert in my code and not navigator.notification.alert().

Comment: Hi Vinay yes I did it. Even the pagecreate and pageshow are working fine, the only that is not working is pageinit.

Comment: Hi Sebastian i have uploaded the working code in jsfiddle.checkout the link below and have a closer look on th js i have added because i think the improper js might be causing the problem for you.http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay/hQGGQ/35/

Comment: Hi Vinay thanks, now it is working, it looks like jquery mobile was in a wrong version or something.

Comment: Also note, that it should be `.on()` instead of `.live()` for jQuery 1.7+

Comment: Actually, I think jquerymobile still uses .live and .bind.